# EF Transaction and Async

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I'm using EF 6 in ASP.NET MVC. I'm running some tasks in the background so I'm using a new EF context and the Task class to execute it. The async task is divided into 3 smaller tasks that should also run async but within the same DB transaction. I cannot use SaveAsync because my code is called from sync and async contexts.

```
Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        CalculateAmounts(id);

                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    dbContext.Dispose();
                }
            });
```

The method CalculateAmounts is the one that created 3 more tasks. How should I deal with the transactions?

On the hand, I'm getting some errors when the tasks are working together, like DataReader already opened. Should I create a context for each task? in that case, how to make them all part of the same transaction?

Comment: `Task.Run` is almost never a good idea in ASP.NET applications. You either are making tasks you can't guarantee will get completed before the AppDomain is shut down or are just adding overhead and decreasing the scaleability of your website.

Comment: I think your comment is right if you think about long running tasks. I'm talking about tasks that take less than 10 seconds. If the AppDomain shuts down it will be a disaster in any case (doing it in just one thread or multiple threads).

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you cannot do what you want and here is why:

> The async task is divided into 3 smaller tasks that should also run
>   async but within the same DB transaction

A single database connection tipically can only run 1 transaction at a time. Which means you would need 3 concurrent connections.

You could still have a [distributed connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction) wrapping these 3 connections using a [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx). The problem is that the TransactionScope is invisible from any thread that is not the one that it's been initiated in. Actually, TS is thread-static and ADO.NET checks it for the current thread to determine whether it should commit multiple transactions together or roll them all back. Anyway, it won't work for you.

Starting from .NET 4.5.1, there's an option you can pass a `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption` to the TransactionScope but it won't make it support multiple threads inside. It will only make it to support `async / await`.

**TL;DR: You are better off doing everything you can in parallel and then commiting everything in a serial way.**

Comment: You're proposing that the tasks don't save anything and when all of them are done I save to the DB and commit? the problem is that I'm running an ASP.NET MVC app and Tasks are letting me return the page to the user while I do some stuff in the background. As far as TransactionScope, Microsoft recommends using dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction from EF6 onwards.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm proposing.

Comment: Yes, dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction should be used for most cases. If you want to commit multiple internal transactions within a global distributed transaction you are still tied to TransactionScope.

Comment: "the problem is that I'm running an ASP.NET MVC app and Tasks are letting me return the page to the user while I do some stuff in the background." <- I did not quite understand this.. Do you want to wait for tasks? What do you want?

Comment: I cannot wait for all the tasks. I do some things sync, start the tasks in the background and return the page with the intermediate results (the ones calculated in a sync.). I would love to be able to return intermediate results while I can continue working with a big transaction.